# T-SQL calculate hierarchy/parents

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to calculate the "hierarchy" column based on NR and NR_FROM-NR_TO, I'm not sure how to create a CTE/VIEW with such hierarchy column. This is what the result should look like:

```
+------+----------------------+---------+-------+---------------------------+
|  NR  |         Text         | NR_FROM | NR_TO |         HIERARCHY         |
+------+----------------------+---------+-------+---------------------------+
| 1020 | AAAAAAAAAAAA         |         |       | /1380/1345/1300/1080/1051 |
| 1040 | BBBBBBB              |         |       | /1380/1345/1300/1080/1051 |
| 1045 | CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC  |         |       | /1380/1345/1300/1080/1051 |
| 1051 | DDDDDDDDDDD          |    1020 |  1045 | /1380/1345/1300/1080      |
| 1060 | EEEEEE               |         |       | /1380/1345/1300/1080      |
| 1080 | FFFF                 |    1051 |  1060 | /1380/1345/1300/1092      |
| 1090 | GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG     |         |       | /1380/1345/1300/1092      |
| 1090 | So. betr. Erlöse     |         |       | /1380/1345/1300/1092      |
| 1092 | Betriebl. Rohertrag  |    1080 |  1090 | /1380/1345/1300           |
| 1100 | Abschreibungen       |         |       | /1380/1345/1300/1280      |
| 1100 | Abschreibungen       |         |       | /1380/1345/1300/1280      |
| 1110 | Personalk. Basis     |         |       | /1380/1345/1300/1280      |
| 1110 | Personalk. Basis     |         |       | /1380/1345/1300/1280      |
| 1120 | Personalk. Zusatz    |         |       | /1380/1345/1300/1280      |
| 1264 | Beratungsaufwand     |         |       | /1380/1345/1300/1280      |
| 1265 | sonstiger Aufwand    |         |       | /1380/1345/1300/1280      |
| 1280 | Gesamtkosten         |    1100 |  1265 | /1380/1345/1300           |
| 1300 | EBIT                 |    1000 |  1280 | /1380/1345                |
| 1310 | Zinsaufwand          |         |       | /1380/1345                |
| 1312 | Sonst. neutr. Aufw   |         |       | /1380/1345                |
| 1320 | Neutraler Aufwand    |    1310 |  1312 | /1380/1345                |
| 1322 | Zinserträge          |         |       | /1380/1345/1330           |
| 1323 | Sonst. neutr. Ertr   |         |       | /1380/1345/1330           |
| 1324 | Verr. kalk. Kosten   |         |       | /1380/1345/1330           |
| 1330 | Neutraler Ertrag     |    1322 |  1324 | /1380/1345                |
| 1345 | DSDSDSDSDSDD         |    1300 |  1320 | /1380                     |
| 1345 | DSDSDSDSDSDD         |    1330 |  1330 | /1380                     |
| 1355 | FDSFDSFSDFDSFSFSD    |         |       | /1380                     |
| 1380 | DDDAAA               |    1345 |  1355 | /                         |
+------+----------------------+---------+-------+---------------------------+
```

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a correlation between NR, NR_FROM, NR_TO and HIERARCHY. Please edit the question to include the SQL code you've tried so far, along with the related schema and sample data.

Comment: anchor is the Nr which doesnt exist between any from-to...each member has all children with Nr between from-to

Comment: [SWAG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_wild-ass_guess): The root is found by excluding all of the rows with `NR` in any of the ranges from `NR_FROM` to `NR_TO`. That goes in your CTE _anchor_. From there recursively add rows based on `NR_FROM` and `NR_TO`. If you provided usable data, e.g. `declare @Samples as Table ( ...); insert into @Samples ( ... ) values ...;`, it would be much easier to provide a working example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this solution gives you what you need.

**Sample data**

```
create table ranges
(
  nr int,
  txt nvarchar(20),
  nr_from int,
  nr_to int
);

insert into ranges (nr, txt, nr_from, nr_to) values
(1020, 'AAAAAAAAAAAA       ', null, null),
(1040, 'BBBBBBB            ', null, null),
(1045, 'CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC', null, null),
(1051, 'DDDDDDDDDDD        ', 1020, 1045),
(1060, 'EEEEEE             ', null, null),
(1080, 'FFFF               ', 1051, 1060),
(1090, 'GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG   ', null, null),
(1090, 'So. betr. Erlöse   ', null, null),
(1092, 'Betriebl. Rohertrag', 1080, 1090),
(1100, 'Abschreibungen     ', null, null),
(1100, 'Abschreibungen     ', null, null),
(1110, 'Personalk. Basis   ', null, null),
(1110, 'Personalk. Basis   ', null, null),
(1120, 'Personalk. Zusatz  ', null, null),
(1264, 'Beratungsaufwand   ', null, null),
(1265, 'sonstiger Aufwand  ', null, null),
(1280, 'Gesamtkosten       ', 1100, 1265),
(1300, 'EBIT               ', 1000, 1280),
(1310, 'Zinsaufwand        ', null, null),
(1312, 'Sonst. neutr. Aufw ', null, null),
(1320, 'Neutraler Aufwand  ', 1310, 1312),
(1322, 'Zinserträge        ', null, null),
(1323, 'Sonst. neutr. Ertr ', null, null),
(1324, 'Verr. kalk. Kosten ', null, null),
(1330, 'Neutraler Ertrag   ', 1322, 1324),
(1345, 'DSDSDSDSDSDD       ', 1300, 1320),
(1345, 'DSDSDSDSDSDD       ', 1330, 1330),
(1355, 'FDSFDSFSDFDSFSFSD  ', null, null),
(1380, 'DDDAAA             ', 1345, 1355);
```

**Solution**

```
with cte as
(
  select r.nr, r.txt, r.nr_from, r.nr_to, 1 as lvl, convert(nvarchar(100), '') as hierarchy
  from ranges r
  where not exists ( select 'x'
                     from ranges r2
                     where r2.nr_from <= r.nr
                       and r2.nr_to >= r.nr)
    union all
  select r.nr, r.txt, r.nr_from, r.nr_to, lvl+1, convert(nvarchar(100), cte.hierarchy + '/' + convert(nvarchar(4), cte.nr))
  from ranges r
  join cte
    on  cte.nr_from <= r.nr
    and cte.nr_to >= r.nr
)
select cte.nr,
       cte.txt,
       cte.nr_from,
       cte.nr_to,
       case when cte.lvl = 1 then '/' else cte.hierarchy end as hierarchy
from cte
where not exists ( select 'x'
                   from cte c2
                   where c2.nr = cte.nr
                     and c2.lvl > cte.lvl )
order by cte.nr;
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=bce471c3881736bdf8d126e347ae7b92)

Comment: Your results start the hierarchy with `/1345` rather than `/1380` as in the OP's expected results.

Comment: @HABO, good catch. Should be fixed now. Still is not a 100% match with OP's result, but I do not think it is on my end now. Nr `1020` produces hierarchy `/1380/1345/1300/1092/1080/1051`. I think OP forgot the `1092` in his expected result (`1092` is parent for [`1080`,`1090`]).

Comment: Hey, looks great (haven't tried it yet). Yes, my bad, there is 1092 missing. Thanx